# Iterating LinkedBlockingQueue in batches without removing items

Tags: java, multithreading

Is there a way to iterate a LinkedBlockingQueue starting with a specific index number?

I have a LinkedBlockingQueue that contains a list of changes to make to a game world. It works perfectly fine when I'm actually making those changes, which involves iterating the queue, using the object polled this iteration, and then removing it from the queue.

The next time the process runs, iterating the queue from the beginning works because we had removed all "used" items.

However, I also have a preview mode, where the changes from the queue need to read and shown to the player, but not actually removed from the queue yet (since they're not officially "used")

These are all done in batches of 1000 so we don't overload network traffic or the clients.

I'd rather not have to re-iterate the queue each "batch" and use something to tell us to continue on until a specific index - and I'd rather not create a secondary queue or "holder".

Comment: Are you actually using the blocking features of LinkedBlockingQueue?  i.e.: is **drainTo**, **put**, or **take** ever called?  If not, I would use **LinkedList** instead, and wrap it with **Collections.synchronizedList**.  If you need the Queue<T> features, you could synchronize manually.

Comment: Possibly not, this code was written a year ago and based on existing code. We query a database, build the results, then `addAll` to the queue. A repeating task then polls the queue 1k items at a time, to use those objects for world changes. I'm guessing it was used to make removing items during iteration easier, but that could be done when using an iterator on a list too.

Comment: So the only methods we're using is `addAll`, `iterator`, `isEmpty` and `remove`

Comment: I've changed it to `List<Handler> worldChangeQueue = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Handler>());` but I need to find how to properly iterate from a starting index. I tried using the `listIterator` method but I'm guessing that's not thread-safe because I got several `CMEs`

Comment: Could you specify how many producers and consumers you might have for both cases (preview and non-preview)?

Comment: Nevermind, I was still using `.remove` on the LinkedList, not `iterator.remove`.